# update contact info based on input fields through tsql

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application that I am developing that has an 'my profile' page. This page grabs all the users info and populates the appropriates fields. [image]

Certain details have been blacked out for privacy reasons. This is working great. What i want to achieve is the ability for the user to edit any of these text fields, and hit the 'update information' button. I am not sure how to do this.

Here is my code behind for what I have working so far.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            grabData();
        }
    }

    protected void grabData()
    {
        HttpCookie cookieLogin = Request.Cookies[Constants.CK_CAUSE_MARKETER_ID];

        string sql = "SELECT * " +
                    "FROM CauseMarketers m with(nolock)" +
                    "INNER JOIN CauseMarketer_Contacts t with(nolock) ON t.CauseMarketerID = m.CauseMarketerID " +
                    "INNER JOIN CauseMarketer_Companies q ON q.CauseMarketerID = m.CauseMarketerID " +
                    "WHERE m.CauseMarketerID = " + cookieLogin.Value; 


        DataTable Results = Utils.SQLUtils.GetDataTable("TFOUNDATION", sql);
        DataRow FirstResult = Results.Rows[0];

        userFirstName.Text = FirstResult["FirstName"].ToString();
        userLastName.Text = FirstResult["LastName"].ToString();
        userCompanyName.Text = FirstResult["CompanyName"].ToString();
        userAddress.Text = FirstResult["Address1"].ToString();
        userAddress2.Text = FirstResult["Address2"].ToString();
        userCity.Text = FirstResult["City"].ToString();
        userZip.Text = FirstResult["ZipCode"].ToString();



    }
```

Comment: You'll need to write an UPDATE statement. Also, why are you using the NOLOCK query hint?

Comment: I'm sorry. I dont know what you mean. Can you explain what you mean regarding the NOLOCK query hint

Comment: `INNER JOIN CauseMarketer_Contacts t with(nolock)` - you have the `NOLOCK` query hint there

Answer (score 0):

Implement update information button click event.

```
<asp:Button ID="UpdateId" runat="server" Text="Update Information" OnClick="UpdateId_Click" />
```

If above the asp.net button then button client event look something like below.

```
 protected void UpdateId_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // write update sql. 
        }
```

During first page load anyway information will get loaded based on your code. When user clicks on button this click event gets fired and you can capture all form information and send to db for update.